# Dynamic filter bar using tag links in tumblr

Tags: dynamic, filter, tags, tumblr

I have 10 links to 10 TagPages, when clicked they take you to a page with all the posts with that tag.

That’s easy enough.

I’d like to know if its possible to stack more than one tagged post in a page. For example when all the “red” tagged posts are showing you can click and load in the “blue” tagged posts without leaving the page.

The 10 links then behave like a filtering system. You can then show any combination of tagged posts in one page… click once and load them in, click again to hide the posts.

I hope that all makes sense.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can load in posts by tag with Tumblr's API: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

The call for each of your tags would look something like this (square brackets marking areas you'll need to change):

```
URL = http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[base-hostname]/posts?api_key=[key]&tag=[tagname]&jsonp=?

$.ajax(URL, {
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // do something with your data
  }
});
```

Updated with a more specific example:

You'd need to create a function for each click of your tag navigation. So let's say you built out your navigation in simple HTML, you'd want to create a function for each of those clicks.

HMTL:

```
<nav class="tag-nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/tagged/portrait" class="portrait">Portrait</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tagged/landscape" class="landscape">Landscape</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS:

```
$('.tag-nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // grab classname from the link that was just clicked
    var tagName = $(this).attr('class');

    // go get our tagged posts
    getTaggedPosts(tagName);
});

var getTaggedPosts = function (tag) {
    // this is where your AJAX call will go

    // bonus points if you check to see if you've already made the AJAX call
    // and stored the posts somewhere else on the page
};
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

This is quite advanced for my primitive coding knowledge. I do understand it a bit, but what would my links to the different tags look like in html?

Comment: also, is there a way to style active links once clicked. is that a simple a:active style.

Comment: a:active is the act of actually clicking a link, nothing to do with where you are currently navigated to.

Comment: Updated my answer with more specific example.